# iOS cocoapods - Reasons for automatic removal of pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I had uploaded a `cocoapod` called BlueShift-iOS-SDK around 8 months ago which was working fine then with

`pod install`

But, it seems like i am not able to do so as it's now missing in cocoapods repository. Any reasons why it is not currently listed in the cocoapods. Could someone suggest what might be the possible reasons for automatic removal for any pod ?

When i try now pod install

it shows

[!] Unable to find a specification for `BlueShift-iOS-SDK`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually such don't happen. Probably it might be a bug with cocoa pod. try pushing the pod once again to the cocoa pod trunk or try to communicate this issue with the cocoapod team.